# Exception when doing a .getAs operation on a Spark Row in production. Works fine locally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a generic code that given a set of Keys and a dataFrame will find duplicates of that key set in the Dataframe 
**The code that didn't work:**

```
case class DuplicateRecord(
    datasetName: String,
    duplicateKeys: String,
    duplicateCount: Long
  )

def findDuplicatesInDF(
    spark: SparkSession
    inputName: String,
    inputDataFrame: DataFrame,
    groupColumns: Seq[String]): Dataset[DuplicateRecord] = {

    import spark.implicits._

    val keys = groupColumns.map(x => col(x))
    val idToCounts = inputDataFrame
      .groupBy(keys: _*)
      .agg(count(keys(0)).as("duplicateKeyCount"))

    idToCounts
      .filter(col("duplicateKeyCount") > 1)
      .map { idToCount =>
        DuplicateRecord(
          inputName,
          groupColumns.map(x => idToCount.getAs(x).toString).mkString(","),
          idToCount.getAs("duplicateKeyCount").toString.toLong)
      }
  }
```

The above code worked fine locally. However, it failed in production with

```
 Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:375)
```

***Code that worked:***

```
case class DuplicateRecord(
    datasetName: String,
    duplicateKeys: String,
    duplicateCount: Long
  )

case class IdToCounts(
    mergedKey: String,
    duplicateKeyCount: Long
  )

def findDuplicatesInDF(
    spark: SparkSession,
    inputName: String,
    inputDataFrame: DataFrame,
    groupColumns: Seq[String]): Dataset[DuplicateRecord] = {

    import spark.implicits._

    val keys = groupColumns.map(x => col(x))
    val idToCounts = inputDataFrame
      .withColumn("mergedKey", concat_ws(",", keys: _*))
      .groupBy(col("mergedKey"))
      .agg(count(col("mergedKey")).as("duplicateKeyCount"))
      .as[IdToCounts]

    idToCounts
      .filter(idToCount => idToCount.duplicateKeyCount > 1)
      .map { idToCount =>
        DuplicateRecord(inputName, idToCount.mergedKey, idToCount.duplicateKeyCount)
      }
  }
```

I understand that this is to do with the fact that Spark runs on a single JVM instance in local mode. But with multiple executors and the data being partitioned in prod was leading to an indeterministic behavior where spark wasn't able to understand where to pull the data from to complete the operation. However, I would like to understand the exact issue and haven't gotten convincing answers in the existing Stack overflow questions related to this. Any insight into this will be super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: It seems the error comes at the very first part, see your spark session creation.

Comment: @Lamanus: I didn't understand? The session is created in the main function and passed to this function. Besides, this doesn't explain why the code worked when I tweaked the operations. Both of them should've given me the same issue about spark Session if the session creation was an issue.

Comment: `A master URL must be set in your configuration` You don't have master on the cluster.

Comment: @Lamanus: I don’t think the spark config is the issue.  why would the code that ended up working not have this issue when both the codes had the same exact way of configuring the sparkSession?

Comment: whatever i don't know but the error says that. I cannot figure out with the limited code and env.

Comment: what if you change the dataframe to rdd and take as their? `rdd.as[]`